# Want to call .ascx file from master page upon button click in asp.net web form application

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have created `.Master, .aspx` and `.ascx` pages. I want to call .ascx page upon click on button in .master page. If the button is not clicked then .ascx should not show up.

Currently,  `Onload` of page, .ascx page is calling because i have used `<uc1:Account runat="server" ID="Account" />`. But i want after click of button not on page load.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

My master page looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Staff.master.cs" Inherits="Admin_Staff" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/Account.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Account" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h4>Account</h4>
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="text" class="  search-query form-control" placeholder="Search" />

        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </span>

    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <uc1:Account runat="server" ID="Account" />
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

My User Control looks like this:

```
<%@  Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Acc.ascx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Controls_Account" %>
<asp:panel id="pnlAcc" runat="server">
                <section id="AccForm">
                              <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" Visible="false">

                    </asp:PlaceHolder>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label">Country: </asp:Label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-md control-label" >New Zealand</asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </section>

</asp:panel>
```

My `.aspx` page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/Staff.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Staff.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Staff" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="StaffContent" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Visibility of the Control to false and change it on Button Click

```
<uc1:Account runat="server" ID="Account" Visible="false"  />
```

And then on button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Account.Visible = true;
}
```

Or you can add the Controls dynamically

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Admin_Controls_Account account = (Admin_Controls_Account)LoadControl("~/Controls/Account.ascx");
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(account);
}
```

Note that for the last option you will have to reload the control each time there is a PostBack so you will have to store the Visibility yourself and recreate the control each time the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to make the control invisible on the master page.

```
<uc1:Account runat="server" ID="Account" Visible="False" />
```

Make it visible on button click.